# how to upload a file using request.Post in python

Tags: python, file-upload, payload, http.client

I have a python script that need to upload a file using **http.client** and **payload** packages. I tried to upload a text file using the parameters of **request.post** but the system crash and display the below error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'files'
```

I tried to pass a files parameter as a tuple as the document said.

## code:

```
import http.client
from IPython.core import payload



files = {'document': open("F:/AIenv/textAnalysis/testin2.txt","r",encoding = "utf-8")}

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("farasa-api.qcri.org") 

headers = { "content-type": "application/json", "cache-control": "no-cache", }

conn.request("POST", "/msa/webapi/lemma", files = files, headers=headers)
res = conn.getresponse()

data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: try `files = {'document': open(path, 'rb', encoding="utf-8')}`

Comment: I would take a look at the [http documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection.request) and look at the keyword arguments accepted.

Comment: @Linny ok based on the documentation it said  one of the argument can be **an open file object**  and that what i tried to do but still not working

Comment: @gnahum i  tried your answer but still the same error

Comment: Just to make sure, the server side can receive a file correct?

Comment: You should be using `requests.post` not `conn.request`